# Create Trigger from Different Table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I have table called `M_InventoryLine`

```
      M_InventoryLine
M_Product_ID  || QtyEntered
101           || 50

        M_Replenish
M_Product_ID  || Level_Min
101           || 20


VW_DaftarBarang_Available
M_Product_ID || Available
101          || 35
```

`QtyEntered` cannot be more than `Available`+`Level_Min` so, I need to `Raise Application Error` in a trigger.

I've tried making trigger like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SAVE_ERROR
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON M_INVENTORYLINE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    AVAILABLE_ST NUMBER;
    MIN_LEVEL NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT AVAILABLE INTO AVAILABLE_ST
    FROM vw_daftarbarang_available 
   where m_product_id = :new.m_product_id;

  SELECT LEVEL_MIN INTO MIN_LEVEL
    FROM M_REPLENISH
   WHERE M_PRODUCT_ID = :NEW.M_PRODUCT_ID;

  IF :NEW.QTYENTERED > :OLD.AVAILABLE + :OLD.MIN_LEVEL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'QUANTITY IS NOT ENOUGH');
  END IF;
END;
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion to make the trigger successful?

Comment: Do you have any error? Have you insert debug print to see what statment are being executed?

Comment: I've ran it via SQLPlus and it says table or view does not exist.. but I have made all tables and views already. What do you mean by insert debug print? I am sorry I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 0):

Edit you trigger to this:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SAVE_ERROR
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON M_INVENTORYLINE
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE 
      AVAILABLE_ST NUMBER;
      MIN_LEVEL NUMBER;
  BEGIN

  SELECT AVAILABLE INTO AVAILABLE_ST FROM vw_daftarbarang_available 
  where m_product_id = :new.m_product_id;

  SELECT LEVEL_MIN INTO MIN_LEVEL FROM M_REPLENISH
  WHERE M_PRODUCT_ID = :NEW.M_PRODUCT_ID;

  IF :NEW.QTYENTERED > AVAILABLE_ST  + MIN_LEVEL
  THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'QUANTITY IS NOT ENOUGH');
  END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Thank you @Vance the trigger successfully created. But, when I execute, it says error as follows : `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.` How can I found the cause of error and solve it ?

Comment: that means that there are more than one AVAILABLE or LEVEL_MIN fetched from tables vw_daftarbarang_available / M_REPLENISH having the new M_PRODUCT_ID that is being inserted. Is there a case in your tables where AVAILABLE and LEVEL_MIN can exist more than once?

Comment: ah, I see. `M_Product_ID` should be selected based on `M_Warehouse_ID` both in `M_Replenish` and `VW_DaftarBarang_Available` so that it has one record. 

My trigger located in `M_InventoryLine` meanwhile `M_Warehouse_ID` located in `M_Inventory`. `M_Inventory` and `M_InventoryLine` connected by `M_Inventory_ID`

Comment: How do I modify the trigger so I can add `where` in trigger with M_Warehouse_ID?

Comment: where are you going to base the  M_Warehouse_ID? I mean if m_product_id  in your where clause depends on :NEW.M_PRODUCT_ID, where does M_Warehouse_ID depends?

Comment: Is it possible to put `M_Warehouse_ID` from `M_Inventory` ?  'cause there's no `M_Warehouse_ID` column in `M_Inventory_Line' should I add another declare ?

Comment: Column `M_Inventory_ID` connects between `M_Inventory` and `M_InventoryLine`

Comment: I think there is no need to do that. i think what you need to do is to restructure your table. Consider this: why would a product_id has more than one AVAILABLE value in your table; same with the case of LEVEL_MIN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93032/discussion-between-vance-and-salma-sulthanah).

Comment: @Vance there is something i didnt understand how this worked ?`:NEW.QTYENTERED ` its a column related to table however there is no` from M_InventoryLine` how you can add if statement to it ?